# accessing files via css in play 2.4

Tags: css, playframework-2.0

I'm new to the play framework and have some issues with accessing files from `css` for the background.

I have this

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET         /assets/*file            controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

in my `routes` file for accessing the `favicon.png` via `html`.

But i have no clue how I can reach my `public/images` folder `via css` for example:

```
.example {background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");}
```

Can you help me? :S

Comment: You can always see what is rendered in the HTML using your developers console. Please note that using `../` goes one folder "backwards" aka parent folder

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your `/public` directory gets published to `http://yourdomain.com/assets/`. So for example your image `/public/images/bg.jpg` can be accessed as `http://yourdomain.com/assets/images/bg.jpg`. In your css you would write

```
.example {background-image: url("/assets/images/bg.jpg");}
```

Comment: Can you access your assets (e.g. `bg.jpg`) directly in your browser? What does your `/public` directory structure look like? After starting the webapp, is `bg.jpg` published to `/target/web/public/main/images`?